# How to pass object as an argument to its method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to define factorial method for Fixnum class and I don't know how to pass this Fixnum as an argument to my method.
Was trying to write something like that

```
def Fixnum.factorial(n)
    n > 1 ? n * factorial(n-1) : 1
end
```

though I knew it would be incorrect. So is there some kind of "this" reserved word to access this number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def factorial
      self > 1 ? self * (self - 1).factorial : 1
  end
end

puts 6.factorial
# 720
```

You know, of course, that this is a silly method of calculating a factorial?

Comment: Silly? How so? (It would be silly if the `*` was a `+`, that much I know).

Comment: You don't need a recursion. Simple loop will do just fine.

Comment: well, mathematically correct, but computationally "silly" (= highly inefficient). A tail-call factorial used in a language with TCO  would be ok. In Ruby I'd probably write `(2..n).inject(1, :*)`.

Comment: Thank you! I came up with final version `(1..self).inject(:*)`

Comment: Recursive method is only good for understanding concept of recursion at general:)

Comment: @user1266027: welcome to stackoverflow. You should accept answers if they are helpful (look for little checkmark to the left).